# Creating a Simple Join Script in Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins, error-000732

I'm trying to create a simple join script in python from an arcgis model, where the only steps are joining a map to a table to produce a map with the table's properties. The attributes joined together are "CNTYFPID" from the shapefile map and "fips" from the textfile. I have tried editing the script produced by arcgis, but it's not working. Where am I going wrong?

```py
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/Documents/ArcGIS/Testing123.mdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Script arguments
Map = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Map == 'tl_2009_us_county_albers_USGS.shp' or not Map:
    Map = "C:/Users/Documents/ArcGIS/Python/tl_2009_us_county_albers_USGS.shp" #provide a default value if unspecified

Crosswalk = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if Crosswalk == '#' or not Crosswalk:
    Crosswalk = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Testing123.mdb\\cao_fips_crosswalk_for_gis" # provide a default value if unspecified)

# Local variables:
Map = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\geography\\tl_2009_us_county\\tl_2009_us_county_albers_USGS.shp"
Final = Map

arcpy.MakeTableView_management(Crosswalk, "fips")

#Process: Join Field
arcpy.AddMessage("Performing Join Field")
arcpy.JoinField_management(Map, "CNTYIDFP", Crosswalk, "fips", "")
```

The python version I am using is 2.7 and the arcgis version is 10.2. [This is what it looks like in modelbuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyCts.png)

> Error message:  "Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Documents/ArcGIS/Yo2.py", line 28, in 
>       arcpy.MakeTableView_management(Crosswalk, "fips")   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py",
>   line 6306, in MakeTableView
>       raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset
>   C:\Users\Documents\ArcGIS\Testing123.mdb\cao_fips_crosswalk_for_gis
>   does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (MakeTableView)."

Comment: Are both the joining fields the same data type (e.g. number to number or text to text)?

Comment: It may be helpful if you add why it's not working (error messages, etc).

Comment: Have you tried just running the join script without the if statements? 
The if statements look odd to me.

Comment: Yes, the model itself works in modelbuilder, I just can't manage to figure out how to convert it to python. I'll add the error message to the original post here

Comment: If I delete the if statments similar messages come back as well

Comment: Are you running the python script through a script tool?

Comment: Through IDLE (Python GUI), or occasionally I've tried it by just trying to run the script in ArcMap, which either fails or breaks arcmap (either way indicating it failed, though they never say why)

Comment: Remove the if statements, save your python file, and create a script tool to run the script (referencing the 0 and 1 data parameter).

Comment: That's the error that IDLE (Python GUI) gives, not arcmap

Comment: I then get "Failed to execute (Script3).
Failed at Fri Jun 20 15:07:42 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.11 seconds)" if I run through the ArcMap script tool (which I presume is what you meant)

Comment: ArcMap sometimes let some of my attempts take a table from a geodatabase, which IDLE refuses to. As far as I can tell that'd be the only difference though.

Comment: Try removing the Make Table View statement, the standalone script example here does not use that method, http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000065000000

Comment: The make table view function works

Comment: With regards to the link you posted, artwork21...would that straight script work, with inFeatures being the map and the joinTable being the table being joined with the map?

Comment: @Taylor, Appears so

Comment: I tried to do a straightforeward conversion in that way, but got similar errors as well.

Comment: Would anything whatsoever need to be added to the standalone script?

Comment: Are you forgetting the computer username in the file paths? C:\\Users\\**USERNAME**\\Documents\\ArcGIS

Comment: I'm guessing the join cannot actively exist if the layer is not consumed through Arc, try the add join method, which will create a new layer from the joined feature layer, http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000064000000

Comment: Yeah, I'm just deleting the username from here since it has my unusual lastname in it.

Answer (score 3):

I've not used [JoinField_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Join_Field/001700000065000000/). Every time I want to join I've used [AddJoin_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Add_Join/001700000064000000/). They appear to do very similar things, so it is possible that the Add Join would work for you.

I am thinking that the problem with your script is that the Join data is of type *feature class*, not that Python has strong types, but both tools specifically call for **layer or table view**. The good news is that it's easy to do this.. use [MakeFeatureLayer_Management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) to create a layer.

```
arcpy.AddMessage("Performing Join Field")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_Management(Map,"Map_Layer")
arcpy.JoinField_management("Map_Layer", "CNTYIDFP", Crosswalk, "fips", "")
```